# Why is an old version of cmake still being used if a new version was installed?

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04

I recently cloned several ROS packages in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). When I tried to build them using cmake, I got this error:

```
CMake Error at rosserial/rosserial/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.7.2 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.5.1
```

So I installed the latest version of cmake. It is installed successfully, it even shows up when I verify the version in terminal:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.19.4
```

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

But when I tried to build the packages after having installed the new version of cmake, I still get the same error,

```
 saying I'm running cmake 3.5.1.
```

This completely baffles me. Is there any difference between having a version of cmake installed vs running?

Any help would be much appreciated.